# Is there a way to add a custom "response" for boolean summary fields in Silverstripe model admin?

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe-4, modeladmin

I want my booleans to give a more friendlier response then true/false. I have seen that I can do Boolan.Nice but that will give me yes/no.

I have used:

```
 class AboutusGallery extends DataObject{
 private static $db = [
    'Description' => 'Varchar',
    'ShowOnHomePage'=> 'Boolean',
];

private static $owns = [
    'Picture'
];
private static $has_one = [
    'Picture' => Image::class,
    'HomePage' => HomePage::class,
];

private static $summary_fields = [
    'Thumbnail' => 'Immagine',
    'Description' => 'Descrizione',
    /* THIS WORKS*/
    'ShowOnHomePageITA' => 'In primo piano',
];

public function ShowOnHomePageITA(){
   return $this->ShowOnHomePage ? 'Si' : 'No';
}
```

ShowOnHomePageITA works and does what I am looking for. But when I do the same in my model admin it brakes.

This is what I am doing:

```
class PageLink extends DataObject {
private static $db = [
    'SortOrder' => 'Int',   
    'Description' => 'Varchar',
    'PageLink' => 'Varchar',
    'ShowOnHeader'=> 'Boolean',
];
private static $has_one = [
    'HomePage' => HomePage::class,
];

private static $summary_fields = [
    'Description',
    /* this does NOT work*/
    'MostraNelHeaderITA' => 'Header',
];

public function MostraNelHeaderITA(){
   return $this->ShowOnHeader ? 'Si' : 'No';
}
```

I have also tried to do some casting or even change the Boolean into varchar without any luck.

As I try to dev/build or flush the project i get the following:

> (!) Fatal error: Call to a member function scaffoldSearchField() on
>   string in
>   D:\Programmazione\WebSites\Pediatra\vendor\silverstripe\framework\src\ORM\DataObject.php
>   on line 2227

So I wonder whether am I doing something wrong or it cannot be done on model admin. Since it works everywhere else except on model admins.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that part of your summary fields array has only a value and the other has a key and a value. Try changing this:

```
-     'Descrizione',
+     'Description' => 'Descrizione',
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've tried the change, unfortunately it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast the returned value as a DBField object, as opposed to a plain string. So...

```
public function MostraNelHeaderITA(){
  $stringValue = $this->ShowOnHeader ? 'Si' : 'No';
  return DBField::create_field('Text', $stringValue);
}
```